# How do I convert a plaintext file to OpenOffice document, so that tabs become indents?

Tags: conversion, formatting, openoffice, text-editing

How do I convert (or paste) a plaintext file to OpenOffice document, so that tabs become indents?

Currently, dynamically wrapped long lines which start with a tab are only indented (by that tab) before the wrap. But after the wrap the lines are not indented at all.

*Additional question: what about converting single newlines to soft returns and multiple newlines to hard returns?*

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single newlines (cr lf) to soft returns (line breaks);

```
Ctrl+F, More options, "Regular expressions"
Find: \r\n
Replace with: \n
```

2 newlines (line breaks) to one hard return (cr lf);

```
Ctrl+F, More options, "Regular expressions"
Find: \n\n
Replace with: \r\n
```

Comment: Hm, now I realize that I marked an answer correct, even when the main question wasn't answered. Should I rename the question title to that additional question, Or should I unmark the answer as correct?

Comment: Well personally I favour the first option :P. You could make a new question for the unanswered portion.

Comment: OpenOffice 3.2.1 does not find "\n" at all in a txt document (created with Vim and containing unix line endings (\n)).
Yes, I have checked the "regular expressions" option.